# Giving column priority first in SQL Search (LIKE) statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL Search statement.......

I want to return values on column **NAME** with first priority and then column **Desc_Work**.

```
Select * from posts
where Province = 'Western_Cape'
and NAME LIKE '%Etienne%' 
or Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%'
```

What changes must I make to this to make sure that the rows in column NAME will be displayed first?

Comment: I take it you are trying to do some sort of scoring?

Comment: Can you list out the columns in the [posts] table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN NAME LIKE '%Etienne%' THEN 1
ELSE 2
END
```

I also believe that you wanted `where Province = 'Western_Cape'
and (NAME LIKE '%Etienne%' 
or Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%')`

**UPDATE**

```
Select * from posts
where Province = 'Western_Cape'
and (NAME LIKE '%Etienne%' 
or Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%')
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN NAME LIKE '%Etienne%' THEN 1
ELSE 2
END
```

I assume you need `(NAME LIKE '%Etienne%'  or Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%')` in brackets - your original query returns records where `(Province = 'Western_Cape' and NAME LIKE '%Etienne%' )
    or Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%')`...

Comment: Updated and some comments added. Depends on what you want to get, you may or may not need brackets (without brackets it will return records where ` Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%'` regardless of Province value

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Full Text Search and rank the results. I think another question asked something similar here: [Giving precedence/weight to a column using FREETEXTTABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710534/giving-precedence-weight-to-a-column-using-freetexttable)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply write this :

`Select NAME, posts.* from posts where Province = 'Western_Cape' and NAME LIKE 'Etienne%' or Desc_Work LIKE '%Etienne%'`

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. The result should show all matches based on `NAME` condition first and then all matches on `Desc_Work`