# SQL Containstable Multiple columns - Which Column Contains Result

Tags: sql-server, filtering, containstable

I have received a spec to add a relevance score to search results, based on which column the result is in. As an example I have a product table with, amongst other fields, keywords,productNames and brands.

I currently check to find a product by link to

```
JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Products, (keywords, productNames, brands), '"NIKE*"')
```

Now this will find the record with the search term on but I need to weight the results by column eg. keywords scores 1, productNames scores 2, brands 4, etc. The sum of the scores I can then add together to give my relevancy of result. i.e. if "Nike" is in all three columns it would score 7, just in brands 4, etc.

To facilitate this I need to know which columns containstable matches on, but haven't found any details on that.

I've looked at the ISABOUT option, but that's for weighting multiple search terms in a single column.

At the moment I have a case statement

```
CASE WHEN CONTAINS (Keywords, '"Nike*"') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN CONTAINS (productNames, '"Nike*"') THEN 2 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN CONTAINS (brands, '"Nike*"') THEN 4 ELSE 0
AS Relevance
```

Which does work, but seems to be very wasteful since containstable must already be doing the work.

If anyone has any ideas then they'll be gratefully received.

Comment: How many records are typically returned by the original statement?  Maybe just wrap that in a `select` that does a `like` on the three columns all in the same `case` after they have all been pulled from the database?

Comment: Hi Dave, Product table for testing is about 700,000 rows, some of our clients have 2 or 3 times that amount so up to about 2,000,000 rows. Returning datasets including multiple variants etc. can be 60/70,000 rows.  I'm paginating the results so only returning top 20 for example, but I still need to process every row to work out what those top 20 are. Obviously from these sort of figures I need to be as efficient as I can.

Comment: Have you tested your multiple `case when contains...` code to see if it returns in an appropriate amount of time?  There is little point in trying to make something more efficient if it hasn't actually been tested for how efficient it is...

Comment: It appears the general practice at present is to `union` with a hardcoded ranking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710534/giving-precedence-weight-to-a-column-using-freetexttable  The only other way I could see you being able to force this ranking is to have search columns that duplicate the data as many times as is the priority to bump it up the search due to the increased hit rate.  So `Brand = 'Nike'` would have a corresponding `BrandSearch = 'Nike Nike Nike Nike'` for priority 4.

Comment: I actually started going down the UNION road, but that would mean hitting the table multiple times.  The example here only shows three columns, but our client can decide which fields they want to include from an admin screen, so there could possibly be a lot more. Client has the option to search in columns like descriptions, etc, which would mean multiple searches through a large table.  I'l;l be back on this later today, will run some tests on it and check the efficiency against the multiple options.